# Getter and Setter Methods in Model class

Tags: java, getter-setter

I am new to this concept, i need a bit understanding the use of getter and setter methods in following situation.

I have three classes as below.

1) ModelClass.java, where i have getter and setter methods.

```
public class ModelClass {

private String name;
private int age;
private String address;

public ModelClass(){

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

}
```

2) StaffInformation.java where i have set the particular staff information through setter method.

```
  public class StaffInformation {

public StaffInformation(){

    ModelClass mc = new ModelClass();
    mc.setName("Khan");
    mc.setAge(30);
    mc.setAddress("NY");

}

 }
```

3) Main.java, Here i want to print out StaffInformation through getter methods which i have in ModelClass.java.
Something like this.

```
    public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
            StaffInformation staff = new StaffInformation();
        ModelClass mc = new ModelClass(); //here is problem
    System.out.println(mc.getAge());
    System.out.println(mc.getName());
    System.out.println(mc.getAddress());

}

  }
```

How get off this...Thanks

Comment: Ideally, you want to be able to say mc.Age = 123;    and int value = mc.Age;    "get" and "set" are java-specific sugar for making that happen.

Comment: Could you show the compiler logs for the error?

Comment: You're never using `StaffInformation`.  How do you expect those values to be anything other than the defaults?

Comment: i have edit my question, i used StaffInformation staff = new StaffInformation(); i for got it to paste here

Comment: If this is all of your code I don't see how you expect it to work.  If there is more, post it.  Also, StaffInformation() extend ModelClas().  And use intention revealing names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem with your code you are creating multiple Model objects try this code

```
   public StaffInformation(){
           ModelClass mc = new ModelClass();
            mc.setName("Khan");
            mc.setAge(30);
            mc.setAddress("NY");
            Main.displayData(mc);

        }
```

Here is your main class

```
  class Main{
    public static displayData(ModelClass mc)
    {
        System.out.println(mc.getAge());
        System.out.println(mc.getName());
        System.out.println(mc.getAddress());

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    StaffInformation sc=new StaffInformation();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this was problem

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you show, the only place where you set `name`, `age`, or `address` is in the constructor to `StaffInformation`. But you also never instantiate `StaffInformation`, so all the fields in `Model` are left as their default values -- `0`, `null`, and `null`, respectively.

Comment: i have edited my question, i used StaffInformation staff = new StaffInformation(); in Main method. i forgot it to paste here –

Comment: Well now you don't display your data?

Answer (score 0):

StaffInformation is creating the ModelClass but not making it visible.
Change StaffInformation to

```
public class StaffInformation {

    public StaffInformation(){
    }

    public ModelClass createModel() {
        ModelClass mc = new ModelClass();
        mc.setName("Khan");
        mc.setAge(30);
        mc.setAddress("NY");
        return mc;
    }

}
```

and change your main to use the ModelClass created:

```
class Main{
    public static void displayData(ModelClass mc)
    {
        System.out.println(mc.getAge());
        System.out.println(mc.getName());
        System.out.println(mc.getAddress());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StaffInformation sc= new StaffInformation();
        ModelClass mc = sc.createModel();
        Main.displayData(mc);
    }
}
```